# Detox with Split.IO

Tags: react-native, e2e-testing, detox

I found a jest mock for split.io for react-native. I am now trying to use this mock so that I do not receive network timeouts because split.io is trying to sync in the background. Here is the mock:

```
jest.mock('@splitsoftware/splitio-react-native', () => {
  const splitio = jest.requireActual('@splitsoftware/splitio-react-native');
  return {
    ...splitio,
    SplitFactory: () => {
      return splitio.SplitFactory({
        core: {
          authorizationKey: 'localhost',
        },
        // Mock your splits and treatments here
        features: {},
        sync: {
          localhostMode: splitio.LocalhostFromObject(),
        },
      });
    },
  };
});
```

I currently put this in my detox init.js file, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything. The only way, so far, I have been able to get my tests to run is to just immediately destroy my SplitFactory as soon as I create it (not through the mock). Obviously, this isn't ideal since I'd have to change the code every time I wanted to run it. I tried creating a .mock.ts file, but that also didn't get read, and when I tried to adjust my metro.config.js, it just failed to run at all. Does anyone have any ideas of how I can get this to run properly in detox for iOS, or have experience with this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with split.io and detox, when a particular split.io would block my tests indefinitely. The only work around i found was

```
await device.disableSynchronization();
```

found [here](https://github.com/wix/Detox/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.Synchronization.md)